# Qual a origem da expressão "Pouca-Terra" associada ao som dos comboios?

Tags: origem-histórica, origem

Há muito que me intriga esta pergunta.

De onde surgiu a expressão "[Pouca-Terra, Pouca-Terra](https://www.dicionarioinformal.com.br/significado/pouca+terra+pouca+terra/21387/)" geralmente associada ao som dos comboios a vapor?

Do pouco que consegui encontrar dizem ser apenas uma [simples onomatopeia](https://ciberduvidas.iscte-iul.pt/consultorio/perguntas/a-onomatopeia-do-comboio-trem/18548), sem outro significado por trás ou [de origem desconhecida](https://ciberduvidas.iscte-iul.pt/consultorio/perguntas/pouca-terra-pouca-terra/29571).

Bem sei que a mente humana tenta encontrar familiaridade no desconhecido (caras em objectos, formas nas nuvens, linguagem em ruídos etc.) fenómeno chamado de [Pareidolia](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pareidolia), mas de todas as possibilidades porquê um aleatório "pouca-terra" para um [ruído abstracto de sonoridade tão mecânica](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=PnHZC3F0xdw) que facilmente encaixaria algo menos elaborado?

Gostava de crer que existe uma história mais fundamentada por trás da associação.

Comment: Possível dica: Estaria a origem relacionada com o carvão mineral ("terra") que o comboio usa para combustão?

Comment: Para mim sempre foi o «pouca terra, pouca terra, u-uuu!». :) Pode ser que alguém encontre mais referências históricas a isso; há por aqui uns detetives exímios...

Comment: Encontrei uns tantos *pouca terra* a partir de 1899, mas nenhum alude a uma história por trás. Mas alguns dizem que é onomatopeia ou melopeia. Uns dizem que é uma onomatopeia muito realista. Eu concordo. E nem é comboios a vapor, que não conheço bem. Dito repetidamente no ritmo certo, lembra-me o barulho das rodas a passar nas juntas dos carris. Muitas outras palavras serviriam. Para mim funcionam palavras curtas com sons plosivos (t, k, p; e d, b e g "fortes"): "bota cá, bota cá", "peca puta, peca puta", "toca a andar, toca a andar". Por exemplo, *sola velha, sola velha* já não funciona.

Comment: Interessante, não tinha pensado na hipótese de melopeia (já aprendi uma palavra nova hoje). O som das rodas nos carris é outra hipótese credível, mas nós facilmente encaixamos quaisquer palavras em cadências (música), daí que me tenha intrigado o específico "pouca-terra". Obrigado pela investigação

Comment: Ele diz apenas "o comboio partiu… murmurando a velha e monotona melopeia tão conhecida... *Pouca terra* … *pouca terra* … *pouca terra* ..." [(Algarve, 1912)](http://memoria.bn.br/DocReader/DocReader.aspx?bib=890073&pesq=%22pouca%20terra%20pouca%22&pasta=ano%20191). Mas de facto, sugere que o ritmo é importante. No caso dele poderá ser da locomotiva. Eu é que, pouco familiarizado com locomotivas a vapor, entoo o *pouca terra, pouca terra* ao ritmo das rodas a passar nas juntas (tal como ouvido dentro da carruagem).

Comment: Isso é verdade, que muitas palavras serviriam (a mim só me soa bem com palavras curtas que tenham sons plosivos). E até pode ter havido uma ideia qualquer por trás do *pouca terra*, mas que não tenha ficado registada ou que nós não consigamos encontrar facilmente na internet...

Comment: Eu, um século ou mais depois da expressão ter sido inventada, associo à terra que o comboio atravessa: o comboio vai cheio de pressa, e acha que a terra que atravessou é pouca. Também vi, raramente, "pouca terra, pouca terra, pouco pão". Não faço ideia se "pouca terra, pouco pão" já era frase feita antes dos comboios, ou se "pouco pão" foi adicionado já depois.

Comment: "*associo à terra que o comboio atravessa: o comboio vai cheio de pressa, e acha que a terra que atravessou é pouca*" essa é uma das hipóteses que sempre me pareceram mais plausíveis. A outra é em referência ao carvão mineral que é pouco para andar mais depressa. Se conseguir ver este vídeo (deve ter de ser em modo incógnito para não ter de registar) por volta dos 46 segundos alguém fala disso https://rr.sapo.pt/artigo/32729/porque-e-que-o-comboio-faz-pouca-terra

Answer (score 1):

Perante a falta de resultados conclusivos deixo aqui as duas hipóteses resultantes das discussões e comentários acima que me pareceram mais justificadas, sem qualquer pretensão de serem "respostas certas" ou definitivas.

1. O "Pouca Terra" refere-se figurativamente à distancia percorrida (terrenos) que o comboio atravessa, que pela sua revolucionária velocidade comparativamente com os restantes transportes terrestres contemporâneos parecia curta.
2. Conforme referido por um senhor nesta [entrevista por volta do segundo 46](https://rr.sapo.pt/artigo/32729/porque-e-que-o-comboio-faz-pouca-terra) (utilizar modo incógnito se não conseguir reproduzir) o "Pouca Terra" pode referir-se ao carvão, na altura de origem mineral ("terra"), que alimentava as caldeiras das locomotivas a vapor. Este parecia sempre "pouco", insuficiente para a alta velocidade pretendida, e requer que os incansáveis maquinistas alimentassem constantemente as fornalhas.